# VBA - Obtain Window logon Event and logoff (Or Lock) event and write to Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, windows-7, excel-2007, event-viewer

I looking at building a template for managing my work hours.

currently i have been looking around for a few examples but haven't found to many that make much sense to me :(.

Would i am looking at is a excel template with a macro to record the First logon event in the morning and the final logoff(Or Lock) Event at the end of the day.

This would be need to be done for a week at a time but just need examples to get me started.

Something a long the lines of...:

If event log date the date is specify in a cell then return the first logon time then return the last logoff or lock event for the same date.

This would just be the basics, i would then fill in the rest to accounts for breaks etc...

Thank you.

Comment: Further to the above, I would like a few examples of how i could engage the window eventlog to pull those dates/times data out. 

thanks

Comment: Do you want to be able to close the "template" during the day? Or you want to keep it open? Will you always log on and out on the same day (meaning you don't log-out past midnight)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and made some assumptions regarding some of the functionality, as you will hopefully be able to adapt it to suit your own needs.

I assumed the following scenario would the most likely :

1. Workbook is **opened in the morning** (place shortcut to workbook in start-up folder), then **manually saved & closed** (I let you have the fun of figuring out how to automatize this one).
2. Workbook is **re-opened before logging-out** (could use a Windows Automated Task for that, *i think*), then again **manually saved & closed**.
3. The worksheet in which you are working is called "**Template**"
4. Suggested columns :  `Date   |   Log-On Time   |   Log-Out Time   |   Total Time`

If you inadvertently open the workbook before really logging-out, simply **erase** the erroneous information, **save**, **close**, and **re-open**.

Finally, here's the code :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim currentTime As Date, currentDay As Date
    currentTime = Format(Now(), "hh:mm")
    currentDay = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Dim template As Worksheet
    Set template = Worksheets("Template")

    With template
        'find the last log-out to use the next line
        last = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If .Cells(last, 2) = "" Then
        'log-on event
            .Cells(last, 1) = currentDay
            .Cells(last, 2) = currentTime

        Else
        'log-out event
            .Cells(last, 3) = currentTime
            .Cells(last, 4) = Format(currentTime - CDate(.Cells(last, 2)), "hh:mm")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT :** I think you may also be able to figure out how to easily calculate break times.